# ¿Qué hace "var _ x = foo()" en Go?

Tags: go

Estoy leyendo el código de un [paquete](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/blob/master/router.go#L158), y veo el siguiente:

```
// Make sure the Router conforms with the http.Handler interface
var _ http.Handler = New()
```

¿Qué hace eso?

Parece que llama al `New()`, de que retorna el tipo de `http.Handler`, pero se descarta la resulta... ¿Por qué hacer eso?

Comment: ¿Alguna de estas ayuda? [Meaning of underscore (blank identifier) in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357028/meaning-of-underscore-blank-identifier-in-go) o [What does a underscore and interface name after keyword var in golang mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194272/what-does-a-underscore-and-interface-name-after-keyword-var-in-golang-mean)

Comment: en el caso que usted menciona no lo se exactamente, pero lo poco que he usado Go el _ en algunas ocasiones se usa como usted dice para descartar "variables/datos" que retornan de la llamada a la funcion, quizas parece raro, pero Go puede devolver multiples parametros, si usted crea una funcion que retorna un int64 y un bool, pero en un momento de su programa solo necesita el bool pues puede emplear _ para descartar el int64, no tengo casi experiencia en Go espero este comentario le ayude Saludos

Comment: @Flimzy listo, espero te sirva y esté entendible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traducción desde SO de la pregunta [what does a underscore and interface name after keyword var in golang mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194272/what-does-a-underscore-and-interface-name-after-keyword-var-in-golang-mean)

---

### Adaptada de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13194635/688393) por [zzzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065241/zzzz):

Provee una validación estática (al momento de compilar) para que se satisfaga la interfaz. El `_` usado como nombre de la variable le indica al compilador que descarte efectivamente el valor RHS, pero que lo valide para evaluar si tiene algún efecto secundario, pero la variable anónima por si misma no toma ningún espacio de proceso.

Es un método útil cuando estás desarrollando y los métodos de la interfaz y/o los métodos implementados por un `type` cambian frecuentemente. Sirve como un escudo o defensa para casos en los que olvides hacer coincidir los métodos de un `type` y de una interfaz en donde el objetivo es hacerlos compatibles. Ayuda a prevenir efectivamente la instalación de una versión fallada (intermedia) usando dicha omisión.

---

### Adaptada de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13194655/688393) por [val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1794051/val):

Al parecer se está creando un valor "dummy" de tipo `http.Handler` asignándole una nueva instancia y luego descartándola (que es lo que significa el underscore en Go, como en `for _, elt := range myRange { ...}` si no te interesa el índice de la enumeración).

Asumo que simplemente corresponde a una validación estática para asegurar que se implemente la interfaz. De esta forma, cuando cambies la implementación, el compilador se quejará antes de tiempo si es que la implementación de la interfaz falla ya que no se podrá hacer el cast de la nueva interfaz.

Comment: Ya encontré que eso está mencionado en la documentación oficial también: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_implements